# Trying to input a specific user list for get-aduser

Tags: powershell, import-from-csv

I'm trying to use a list of usernames to perform a simple `get-aduser` command. It works fine for a single user, but I can't input a file to perform this for a list.

This command works fine for a single user:

```
get-aduser -identity myusername -properties passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires | 
    sort name | ft Name, passwordlastset, Passwordneverexpires | out-file c:\PS\Output.txt
```

This works fine, but rather than use -filter * for all AD or identity pointing to a file, I am completely lost. I have tried doing a get-content and link to a file but I'm just getting into a pickle.

If I have a text file with a list of usernames in, how do I run the above command against that single text file list, rather than all of AD?

As a side query, is there a way that I can perform the above command, but for a specific OU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list that isn't an object, either import it to an object or iterate over the values

Try something like:

```
$Userlist = Get-Content -path 'c:\temp\test.txt'
$Results = $Userlist | ForEach-Object {
    Get-aduser -identity $_ -properties passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires
}
$Results | sort name | ft Name, passwordlastset, Passwordneverexpires | out-file c:\PS\Output.txt
```

This will work as long as you supply valid SamAccountNames in your list

Comment: You legend, thankyou so so so much!! 

How would I change that to point to an OU rather than a list?

If the OU was \\domain\ou\department\finance

Comment: Get-ADUser has a -SearchBase switch which accepts a canonical name (CN)

Comment: Excellent!! Thankyou SO MUCH!

Finally.... sorry.... this works with "out-file" to a txt. If I do export-csv, I get this as an output. Why the difference?!

#TYPE Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData     
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd pageHeaderEntry pageFooterEntry autosizeInfo shapeInfo groupingEntry
033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280    Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo 
9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3

Comment: You should only format when you need to display data. Don't format anything when you export to csv. just use $Results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'PathtoCSV'

Comment: You are amazing. Thankyou so much! I have tried to upvote but sadly I don't have enough reputation for it to show properly!!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way.  You can pipe in identity byvalue.  You can import the csv later and get objects back.

```
get-content userlist.txt | 
Get-aduser -properties passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires | 
sort name | 
select Name, passwordlastset, Passwordneverexpires | 
export-csv users.csv


# searchbase example
get-aduser -filter 'name -like "j*"' -SearchBase 'OU=People,DC=stackoverflow,DC=com'
```

Comment: Nope, I get the error:
**Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SearchBase'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the
argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:1 char:98
+ ... perties passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires -searchbase $ou | sort  ...
+                                                               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser**

Comment: surely you wouldn't need the get-content if you're getting users from the specific OU?

Comment: @RobPowell Set the $ou to the ou you want. But actually -searchbase can only be used with -filter.